# How to delegate facts to localhost from a play targeting remote hosts

Tags: ansible

Ansible version: 2.9.16, running on RHEL 7.9, python ver = 2.7.5, targeting windows 2016 servers. ( should behave the same for linux target servers too)

My playbook has two plays. One targets 3 remote servers ( Note: serial: 0 i.e Concurrently  )  and another just the localhost. In play1 I am trying to delegate facts obtained from each of these hosts to the localhost using delegate_facts and delegate_to. The intent is to have these facts delegated to a single host ( localhost ) so I can use it later in a play2 (using hostvars)  that targets the localhost. But strangely thats not working. It only has information from the last host from Play1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Switched to using host specific variables in inventory to avoid confusion that Iam just trying to print hostnames of a group. Even here its a gross simplification. Pretend that var1 is obtained dynamically for each server instead of being declared in the inventory file.

My inventory file **inventory/test.ini** looks like this:

```ini
    [my_servers]
    svr1 var1='abc'
    svr2 var1='xyz'
    svr3 var1='pqr'
```

My Code:

```yaml
    ## Play1
    - name: Main play  that runs against multiple remote servers and builds a list.
      hosts: 'my_servers'  # my inventory group that contains 3 servers svr1,svr2,svr3
      any_errors_fatal: false
      ignore_unreachable: true
      gather_facts: true
      serial: 0
    
      tasks:
    
          - name: initialize my_server_list as a list and delegate to localhost 
            set_fact:
              my_server_list: []
            delegate_facts: yes
            delegate_to: localhost
    
          - command: /root/complex_script.sh
            register: result

          - set_fact:
            my_server_list: "{{ my_server_list + hostvars[inventory_hostname]['result.stdout'] }}"
            # run_once: true  ## Commented as I need to query the hostvars for each host where this executes.
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
  
    
          - name: "Print list - 1"
            debug:
              msg: 
                - "{{ hostvars['localhost']['my_server_list']  | default(['NotFound']) | to_nice_yaml }}" 
            # run_once: true
    
          - name: "Print list - 2"
            debug:
              msg: 
                - "{{ my_server_list | default(['NA']) }}"
```

```yaml
    ## Play2
    - name: Print my_server_list which was built in Play1
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: true
      serial: 0
    
      tasks:
    
          - name: "Print my_server_list without hostvars "
            debug:
              msg: 
                - "{{ my_server_list  | to_nice_json }}" 
            # delegate_to: localhost
    
    
          - name: "Print my_server_list using hostvars"
            debug:
              msg: 
                - "{{ hostvars['localhost']['my_server_list']  | to_nice_yaml }}" 
            # delegate_to: localhost
```

```yaml
###Output###

$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/test.ini delegate_facts.yml
    
    PLAY [Main playbook that runs against multiple remote servers and builds a list.] ***********************************************************************************************************
    
    TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [svr3]
    ok: [svr1]
    ok: [svr2]
    
    TASK [initialize] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [svr1]
    ok: [svr2]
    ok: [svr3]
    
    TASK [Build a list of servers] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [svr1]
    ok: [svr2]
    ok: [svr3]
    
    TASK [Print list - 1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [svr1] =>
      msg:
      - |-
        - pqr
    ok: [svr2] =>
      msg:
      - |-
        - pqr
    ok: [svr3] =>
      msg:
      - |-
        - pqr
    
    TASK [Print list - 2] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [svr1] =>
      msg:
      - - NA
    ok: [svr2] =>
      msg:
      - - NA
    ok: [svr3] =>
      msg:
      - - NA
    
    PLAY [Print my_server_list] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    
    TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost]
    
    TASK [Print my_server_list without hostvars] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] =>
      msg:
      - |-
        [
            "pqr"
        ]
    
    TASK [Print my_server_list using hostvars] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] =>
      msg:
      - |-
        - pqr
    
    PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    svr1                       : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    svr2                       : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    svr3                       : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    
    Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 13 seconds

###**Expected Output**###
I was expecting the last two debug statements in Play2 to contain the values of var1 for all the servers something like this:


    
        TASK [Print my_server_list using hostvars] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
        ok: [localhost] =>
          msg:
          - |-
            - abc
            - xyz
            - pqr
```

Comment: If you are looking to get the list of servers in `my_servers` group, why not use the `groups['my_servers']` ansible fact? This will automatically give you a list of 3 servers `[svr1, svr2, svr3]`.

Comment: This is just a sample code to demonstrate the issue. The real playbook is more complex.

Comment: So you want `my_server_list` to contain the 3 hosts of your `my_servers` group?

Comment: How could an accumulator works concurrently? Better to store on each host facts without any delegation, so no concurrency or accumulator issue, then on localhost, combine the data from other host with something like `groups.my_servers | map('extract', hostvars, 'my_server_list') | flatten`

Comment: yes but In the real playbook i do not know the list of hosts to loop through. This example is a simplification intended to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @seshadri_c  think of my_server_list as a list that contains information collected by running commands on different hosts. As I said this is just a simplification

Comment: My thinking is that the concept is working in theory as it is fetching the list for the last server (svr1). Just not sure why it is overwriting the other servers and not appending.

Comment: So the append operation appends only that server's `inventory_hostname` to the `my_server_list`. It is not overwriting. After setting for `svr1`, when it reaches `svr2`, it's an empty list and appends `svr2` and so on.

Comment: @seshadri_c so how do I append to a list thats delegated to localhost ( see the initialization task ) .. is that possible ? Thanks for the help will check back later 3AM here now  lol:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_server_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_server_list
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_server_list:
  - svr1
  - svr2
  - svr3
```

---

There are many other ways how to create the list, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups.my_servers }}"
      run_once: true
```

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.inventory_hostname') }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

Q: *"**Fill the list with outputs gathered by running complex commands.**"*

A: Last example above shows how to create a list from *hostvars*. Register the result from the complex command, e.g.

```sh
shell> ssh admin@srv1 cat /root/complex_script.sh
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig wlan0 | grep inet | cut -w -f3
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command: /root/complex_script.sh
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        my_server_list: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.result.stdout') }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_server_list
```

gives

```yaml
  my_server_list:
  - 10.1.0.61
  - 10.1.0.62
  - 10.1.0.63
```

---

Q: *"**Why the logic of delegating facts to localhost and keep appending them to that list does not work?**"*

A: The code below (simplified) can't work because the right-hand-side *msl* value still comes from the *hostvars* of the *inventory_host* despite the fact `delegate_facts: true`. This merely puts the created variable *msl* into the localhost's hostvars

```yaml
- hosts: my_servers
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        msl: "{{ msl|default([]) + [inventory_hostname] }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
```

Quoting from [Delegating facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts)

> To assign gathered facts to the delegated host instead of the current host, set delegate_facts to true

As a result of such code, the variable *msl* will keep the last assigned value only.

Comment: perhaps I was not clear ... in my sample playbook iam using inventory_hostname for illustration purposes *ONLY*. In my real playbook i intend to fill the list with outputs gathered by running complex powershell/bash commands and not just simply append hostnames to a llist. Thanks for taking the time to help me out though !

Comment: I modified my question to avoid the confusion. Please take a look. Thanks !

Comment: If you want to be clear and avoid confusion [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Comment: thanks . That works but I dont understand why.. Can you please explain how the  hostvars|json_query('*.result.stdout') is able to capture  results from all host when it is set to run once ? how does it know the query the correct list of hosts ? Also maybe can you tell what was wrong with my approach. Thanks a lot. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok,I I think I know how your technique works. But Iam not sure why I cannot grab the result from hostvars like:  hostvars[inventory_hostname]['result.stdout']  it keeps saying variable undefined. I will edit my question so you can see what Iam trying

Comment: sorry I forgot to accept this as an answer. But would be nice to know why the logic of delegating facts to loalhost and keep appending to that list does not work. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're welcome! The logic does not work because the right-hand-side always comes from the current host. I've updated the answer.