# Can't generate a list of hosts' IPs delegated to localhost

Tags: ansible

As in the title, I'd like to create a list of IPs assigned to each of the hosts in a group, but only one IP gets recorded in the list (the last one, so the first one is probably overwritten).

The tasks are defined this way:

```yaml
-
  hosts: general
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get all IPs
      set_fact:
        ip_list: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: false
-
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Display gathered IPs
      debug:
        var: ip_list
-
```

`hosts.yml`:

```yaml
---
general:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
...
```

After the playbook stops, debug shows only one IP:

```
TASK [Get all IPs] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> localhost]
ok: [host2 -> localhost]

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************

TASK [Display gathered IPs] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ip_list": "10.11.12.13"
}
```

Something similar was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525326/how-to-delegate-facts-to-localhost-from-a-play-targeting-remote-hosts), but answers given there don't work in my case.

Replacing `"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host }}"` with simply `"{{ ansible_host }}"` doesn't work either.

How to generate a list of IPs that contains all hosts' IPs?

Comment: Where does the *ansible_host* variable come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration below gives you what you want

```yaml
ip_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
             map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host') }}"
```

For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host1 ansible_host=10.1.0.11
host2 ansible_host=10.1.0.12
host3 ansible_host=10.1.0.13
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ip_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ip_list
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  ip_list:
  - 10.1.0.11
  - 10.1.0.12
  - 10.1.0.13
```