# How to extract multiple hostvars from all hosts in a group?

Tags: ansible

It's a follow up of an issue resolved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77068704/cant-generate-a-list-of-hosts-ips-delegated-to-localhost).

There's need to add another variable from hosts, the `INSTANCE_CLASS`. Hosts variables are saved as extensionless files in `host_vars` directory, carrying host names as the filenames, e.g. `host12`:

```yaml
---
ansible_host: 10.11.12.15
INSTANCE_CLASS: vm_host
...
```

Extracting hostvar from multiple hosts was described in the linked question, however when I tried to create a list of dictionaries instead a list of strings, results weren't as I'd expect.

Attempt #1:

```yaml
  hosts: general
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ip_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Get all IPs
      set_fact:
        ne_hosts:
          - ip: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] }}"
            instance_class: "{{ hostvars[item]['INSTANCE_CLASS'] }}"
      loop: "{{ ip_list }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: true
-
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Display gathered IPs
      debug:
        var: ne_hosts
```

This one overwrites previous variables, leaving just the last one in the array:

```bash
TASK [Display gathered IPs] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ne_hosts": [
        {
            "instance_class": "mdd_controller",
            "ip": "10.11.12.19"
        }
    ]
}
```

Attempt #2:

```yaml
  hosts: general
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ip_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host') }}" ### changed var
  tasks:
    - name: Get all IPs
      set_fact:
        ne_hosts: "ip: {{ ip_list }}, instance_class: {{ INSTANCE_CLASS }}" ### changed line
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: true
-
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Display gathered IPs
      debug:
        var: ne_hosts
```

This one gives the full list of IPs, but only the last instance class is displayed:

```bash
TASK [Display gathered IPs] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ne_hosts": "ip: ['10.11.12.15', '10.11.12.19'], instance_class: mdd_controller"
}
```

What to do to receive something like:

```bash
"ne_hosts": "[
    {ip: '10.11.12.15', instance_class: vm_host},
    {ip: '10.11.12.19', instance_class: mdd_controller}
]"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration below gives you what you want

```yaml
ne_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
              map('extract', hostvars)|
              json_query('[].{ip: ansible_host,
                              instance_class: INSTANCE_CLASS}') }}"
```

For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[general]
host11
host12
host13
```

and the *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host11
ansible_host: 10.1.0.11
INSTANCE_CLASS: vm_host_11

shell> cat host_vars/host12
ansible_host: 10.1.0.12
INSTANCE_CLASS: vm_host_12

shell> cat host_vars/host13
ansible_host: 10.1.0.13
INSTANCE_CLASS: vm_host_13
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: general

  vars:

    ne_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                  map('extract', hostvars)|
                  json_query('[].{ip: ansible_host,
                                  instance_class: INSTANCE_CLASS}') }}"
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "ansible_host: {{ ansible_host }} INSTANCE_CLASS: {{ INSTANCE_CLASS }}"
    - debug:
        var: ne_hosts|to_yaml
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  ne_hosts:
    - {instance_class: vm_host_11, ip: 10.1.0.11}
    - {instance_class: vm_host_12, ip: 10.1.0.12}
    - {instance_class: vm_host_13, ip: 10.1.0.13}
```

---

Note: The above declaration works because the *hosts* of the play are limited to the group *general*. Therefore the list *ansible_play_hosts_all* keeps the same items as *groups.general*. To answer your question:

Q: ***"How to extract multiple hostvars from all hosts in a group?"***

A: A better answer might be

```yaml
ne_hosts: "{{ groups.general|
              map('extract', hostvars)|
              json_query('[].{ip: ansible_host,
                              instance_class: INSTANCE_CLASS}') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Basiclly you are asking how to append an array in ansible.

Try this:

```
- hosts: general
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ip_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname') }}"
    ne_hosts: [] # initial empty array
  tasks:
    - name: Get all IPs
      set_fact:
        ne_hosts: "{{ ne_hosts  + [{'ip': hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] , 'instance_class': hostvars[item]['INSTANCE_CLASS'] }] }}" # append object
      loop: "{{ ip_list }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: true

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Display gathered IPs
      debug:
        var: ne_hosts
```

Comment: OK, it worked, however I had to change `ansible_host` to `ansible_hostname` in `vars.ip_list` value: please correct it in your answer.